# How do I get the version of workspace member using a method from the parent member?

Tags: rust

[This question has a trash repo with minimum reproducible code](https://github.com/erayerdin-trash/rust001).

## How to reproduce

I have created the project like this:

```sh
cargo new foo --bin
cd foo
cargo new bar --bin
```

Then, I have updated `Cargo.toml` as below:

```
[package]
name = "foo"
version = "0.1.0" # notice the version
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]

[workspace]
members = ["bar"]
```

And then, I have updated `bar/Cargo.toml` seen as below:

```
[package]
name = "bar"
version = "0.2.0" # notice the version
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
foo = { path = ".." }
```

> Notice the versions of both `Cargo.toml`.

Then, I have created a function in `src/lib.rs` like this:

```rust
pub fn get_version<'a>() -> &'a str {
    env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION")
}
```

Then, in `bar/src/main.rs`, I used it as below:

```rust
use foo::get_version;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", get_version());
}
```

Then I run `cargo run -p bar`.

## The Problem

I will possibly have multiple workspace members that will use `foo::get_version`. I expect them to print out their *own* versions. In this example, `foo` is `0.1.0` and `bar` is `0.2.0`.

So, I want the `main` function of `bar` to print out `0.2.0`, yet it prints out `0.1.0`, which is expected because `env!` macro takes environment variable and directly passes it into final binary. When I compile, it compiles `foo::get_version`, which is inside `foo` and `CARGO_PKG_VERSION` is `0.1.0` on compile time.

However, this is not the behavior I desire. I desire it to get the version of *the crate that `get_version` is used* and I want to keep it in `foo` because, again, I'd like to reuse it again and again on possible different workspace members.

Hence the question, how do I get the version of workspace member using a method from the parent member?

---

## Environment

- rustc 1.55.0

Comment: My need was the other way around. So your idea of get_version() inside src/lib.rs worked very well for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This cannot possibly work. Functions cannot be generic over their calling contexts.

You can get some info regarding who called the function *at run-time* by using [`#[track_caller]`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2091-inline-semantic.md). However, that doesn't help that the information you want can only be retrieved in the context of the individual crates *at compile-time* anyway.

Your only recourse is to use a macro:

```
macro_rules! get_version {
    () => {
        env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION")
    }
}
```

With a macro, code is generated at the call-site, which means that, if called in one of the "child" crates, `env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION")` will retrieve the "child" crate's version. You can of course write more code in the macro if the goal of the original function was intended to encompass more logic into the "parent" crate. But that's the only way to get access to crate-specific info like this.